# CSS UL formatting causes other elements to wrap

Tags: html, css

Hoping this will be a quick/easy one, but I can't seem to find the correct search terms on-line.

### Goal

I would like to create a list of icons / images, marked up with CSS into a horizontal menu. However, while I achieve this effect, any other elements on the page do not seem to accept it as a block element.

I know I'm doing something wrong (and likely a trivial something).

### (applicable) HTML

```
<ul id="alist">
<li id="t"><a href="#t"></a></li>
<li id="q"><a href="#q"></a></li>
<li id="i"><a href="#i"></a></li>
<li id="l"><a href="#l"></a></li>
<li id="m"><a href="#m"></a></li>
<li id="p"><a href="#p"></a></li>
</ul>

<h1>T</h1>
Lorem ipsum
<h1>?</h1>
Lorem ipsum
<h1>I</h1>
Lorem ipsum
<h1>L</h1>
Lorem ipsum
<h1>M</h1>
Lorem ipsum
<h1>P</h1>
Lorem ipsum
```

### CSS

```
ul#alist
{
    display:inline;
    display:block;
    list-style:none;
}

ul#alist li
{
    text-align:center;  
    float:left;
    width:53px;
    height:53px;
    margin:0px 5px 0px 5px;
}

ul#alist li a
{ 
    width:53px;
    height:53px;
    padding:0px;
    display:block;
}

#t
{
    background-image:url(images/T.png);
}

#q
{
    background-image:url(images/Q.png);
}

#i
{
    background-image:url(images/I.png);
}

#l
{
    background-image:url(images/L.png);
}

#m
{
    background-image:url(images/M.png);
}

#p
{
    background-image:url(images/P.png);
}
```

### Current Result (Chrome)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are floating the list items, you'll want to clear the next item in the HTML where you want floating to cease and desist:

```
h1 { clear:both; }
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense; great concise explanation/solution. Fixed the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try to add something like this

```
#t{
background-image:url(images/t.png);
background-size:100px 100px; /*YOUR IMAGE WIDTH AND HEIGHT*/
padding-left:120px; /*YOUR IMAGE WIDTH PLUS 20px*/
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```